# element of the list and iterator to the next element

Tags: c++, list, std

I don't get what Bjarne has on mind stating:

> A list iterator must be something more complicated than a simple
>   pointer to an element because an element of a list in general does not
>   know where the next element of that list is. Thus, a list iterator
>   might be a pointer to a link

I know that list's node has pointers to the next and previous nodes. So how it "in general does not know"?

Comment: Mind linking to/mentioning the source (perhaps for a bit of context)?

Comment: He's also probably comparing that to some implementations of the `std::vector<T>::iterator`, which can be as simple as a `T*`

Comment: "*I know that list's node has pointers to the next and previous nodes. So how it "in general does not know"?*" That's because list's node is not just a pointer to an element. You're effectively repeating what you're quoting, just in different words.

Comment: no, I am saying that node knows about next node.

Comment: Yes, which is what Bjarne is saying -- node can know about the next node _because_ node is not simply a pointer to an element.

Comment: and node is not an element? element is the value of node?

Comment: Quoting [Cat Plus Plus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10422258/636019), "*Don't confuse list node with a list element.*" If you _are_ confusing those, then things clearly won't make sense. ;-]

Comment: I just asked: node is not an element? element is the value of node? if not, please explain what the difference between them.

Comment: @cf16: The element is the thing being stored.  The node is the means by which you store the elements and also the means by which you access the other nodes which hold other elements.  The elements themselves have no knowledge of eachother or the nodes that hold them.

Comment: so what is the node value?  _Ty _Myval; // the stored value, unused if head   as we find in list.h

Comment: thanks, thanks, thanks. finally.  : DDD  sometimes it is so hard to understand each other, sometimes it is easy.   ; )  now I get it. thanks you all. I asked about it 5 posts above: why are you not reading me carefully? aha...

Comment: @cf16 : Because Cat Plus Plus _already_ explained it in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For contrast, let's consider an iterator for `std::vector`. Though you probably don't *want* to, you could basically implement it as a simple pointer:

```
template <class T>
class vector {
    T *data;
    size_t current_size;
    size_t alloc_size;
public:
    typedef T *iterator;
    iterator begin() { return data; }
    iterator end() { return data+current_size; }
    // ...
};
```

and since the data in the vector is contiguous, when you do (for example) `++` on the iterator, it would do the right thing (get you to the next item in the vector).

With a linked list, it can't be that simple though -- if you used `typedef` to make iterator an alias for `T *`, it wouldn't work right. When you tried to do `++` on the iterator, it would just increment the pointer, instead of taking you to the next element in the linked list like it needs to.

You need to build some intelligence into the iterator class so operator++ (for one example) knows to "chase" the pointer instead of just incrementing.

```
template <class T>
class list { 

    class node { 
        T data;
        node *next;
        node *prev;
    };
public:
    class iterator {
        node *pos;
    public:
        iterator operator++() {
            return pos = pos->next;
        }
        iterator operator--() {
            return pos = pos->prev;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: and prev is a member of node not iterator obviously?

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse list node with a list element. It *might* be a pointer, but to a node, which contains element and next/prev links. If it were just a pointer to the element, you wouldn't be able to move around with it. (Though it's unlikely to be just pointer, since it typically has to overload operator++ to fetch next pointer instead of incrementing itself).

This isn't true for intrusive lists, where node == element, but that's not std::list.

```
// illustrative
template <typename ElementType>
struct list_node {
    ElementType element;
    list_node *next, *prev;
};
```

Comment: struct _Node
  { // list node
  _Nodeptr _Next; // successor node, or first element if head
  _Nodeptr _Prev; // predecessor node, or last element if head
  _Ty _Myval; // the stored value, unused if head

 private:
  _Node& operator=(const _Node&);
  };    we have next node, previous and value. so how this node doesn't know about next node? and also, how the element isn't the node?

Comment: @cf16: Node does know about next node. Element is a value contained inside the node, not the node itself. In a non-intrusive list, element doesn't even know (and doesn't really care) it's inside the list.